# Magento 2.4.3 p1 command line Area code is not set

Tags: magento2, command-line

I've a custom command line module as follows:

```
<?php
namespace Test\MosIntegration\Console;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class FixOrders extends Command
{
    protected $_helper;
    protected $_state;

    public function __construct(
        \Test\MosIntegration\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
    )
    {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->_state = $state;
        //$this->_state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND);
        parent::__construct();
    }


    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('mosaic:fixorders');
        $this->setDescription('Fix missing orders');
        $this->setDefinition([
            new InputArgument(
                'batch_id',
                InputArgument::REQUIRED,
                __("Batch Id")
            ),
        ]);

        parent::configure();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->_state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND);

    }
}
```

i've already set "$this->_state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND);", but when i ran setup:upgrade, the command prompt still show

```
  [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
  Area code is not set
```

it is very strange because i've 4 others command in another module it works fine, anyone knows what are the problems?

Comment: did you try with $this->_state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);

Answer (score 0):

Might be because of the area try changing for(I've always used admin area for cli command). That being said i'm not sure it will fix your issue.

```
    try {
        $this->state->setAreaCode(Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $output->writeln('<error>' . $e->getMessage() . '</error>');
    }
```

Comment: thx for the reply, i found the problem it is the helper problem, i removed the helper injection in contructor than works fine, not sure the reason.